# Is it possible to fractionally distill a compound made up of substances with very similar boiling points?

Tags: equipment, distillation

Let's say I have a solution that is made up of substances that have very similar boiling points, say less than 5 degrees apart. Is it even possible to fractionally distill those substances, say, using a vacuum still?

Which method is more precise, heating the solution and swapping out condensation vessels as the temperature increases, or having a column with the ability to fractionate in stages?

Comment: Yes, possible. Very good column's needed though.

Comment: What factors contribute to s good column

Comment: You have a SOLUTION not a compound

Comment: If the chemicals form an *azeotrope*, even with a wide separation of b.p. (e.g. ethanol + water), then it may not be feasible to separate by distillation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azeotrope

Comment: There is the concept of a *plate* which is the difference between the liquid composition and the vapor composition. Each plate would have a slightly different temperature. So you'd need a column which in its mechanical construction would have a lot of plates.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik  I’m somewhat familiar with this concept, but does that mean that a portion of the distillate no matter beginning middle or end is partially both substances because the azeotrope forces both to have the same BP

Comment: Yes... for example, whatever proportion of ethanol and water a solution contains to start, as it boils down it tends to ~95.5% ethanol. Azeotropes  can be separated using a third chemical to entrain one of the ingredients, but not through distillation alone.